# How to bind sum of amount in gridview in customized

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, gridview

I had 1 column in database(amount) adding this amount based on type ='x' and type='y' in two different columns of grid.

```
select sum(amount) 
from tbl where type='x';
```

same as another column but,

I need add another column for gridview to display this x-y amount,

How to add in gridview here i am using ascx for and usercontrol grid and customized the grid?